# Clear a whatsapp conversation but keep the media

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have got a group conversation with a lot of messages. I want to clear the messages but want to keep the pictures and videos.

Comment: I typed that wrong. Corrected now.

Comment: Reply, Edit and Updated, thanks for your edit.

Comment: Last time (years back), I clear chat but the media is not removed, leaving many junks in my phone. I wonder if this has been fixed by whatsapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Media, Stored in below Directory :

> `SDcard (Internal Storage) -> WhatsApp -> Media`

**For videos :**

`SDcard (Internal Storage) -> WhatsApp -> Media -> WhatsApp Video`

**For Pictures :**

`SDcard (Internal Storage) -> WhatsApp -> Media -> WhatsApp images`

and **copy** or **Move** anything you want it in Backup Directory (like, save `music in -> Extsdcard -> Music`).

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Upload them to drive or google photos. Open the media in whatsapp and Long press on it you'll see the 3dot feature near top right corner of the screen, click on the 3dot which will give options, choose drive to upload your media.